# Chef Client with client get/delete permissions?

Tags: chef-infra

I'd like to create a chef client for API access that has permission to list and delete all existing and future clients.

I'm using hosted chef, and am able to create a new client (call it X), and assign X permission to get/update/delete other specific clients.

I can't, however, figure out how to configure chef so that whenever a new client is created (programmatically, through the console, etc.), my client X has permission to get and delete it.

It seems that only the admin group is automatically given such permissions. I realize I could create a dummy admin user for this purpose, but since it will be used by a script, I'd prefer to use a client and restrict its permissions to only client get/delete.

Is it possible to configure chef to give a specific client X get and delete permissions on all newly created clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Chef provisioning](https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html). It has a resource for managing chef clients on the chef server.

## Upate

The following blog posting explains how to configure the authorizations of a client enabling it to run a recipe containing Chef provisioning resources:

- http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2015/02/09/quick-tip-create-a-provisioner-node/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though I'm not looking for a resource to manipulate chef clients using "chef-client", I want this client for API access (probably using a library such as https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api). I'm curious if there's a way to configure client creation at the server level so that my specific client has get/delete permissions for all new clients. Thanks!

Comment: @daws I have updated my answer with a blog posting that I think describes what you're looking for.